# Webapp content from dependency war copied locally

Tags: java, maven, web-applications, war

I am writing an application using maven. The end result is a war file. I configured it in such a way that i have a project named "war" which fetches all needed jars and produces the final war. I have a second project named "ui" which contains all ui elements. This ui project also contains files that are to be included in the webapp directory. That's why the ui module is also package as a war file. In the pom.xml of the project "war", I included the following dependency:

```
<dependency>
        <groupId>ui</groupId>
        <artifactId>ui</artifactId>
        <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
        <type>war</type>
</dependency>
```

When I package everything from "war" project, the webapp of "ui" is not only copied in the final war, but also in the local webapp folder of the project "war". Is there a way to deactivate this so that the content of ui's webapp only ends up in the final jar ? Otherwise my "war" project becomes polluted with files and folders from another module and they are never cleaned. So files added in ui and then erased will still be present in "war" project.

Comment: Take a deeper look into [overlays](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-war-plugin/overlays.html)..

Comment: I had a look into overlays but i couldn't find a suitable parameter suiting my needs. The "war" project is always empty so i don't need to set up rules on how files are merged. I only want to make sure files are only copied in the final war file.

Answer (score 0):

You haven't attached war configuration from pom.xml, I assume you're using maven overlays default settings.

Your problem comes from using "war" as project name, which conflicts with overlays defaults. According to WAR plugin [documentation](https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-war-plugin/war-mojo.html#workDirectory):

> workDirectory 
>   Directory to unpack dependent WARs into if needed.
>   Default: ${project.build.directory}/**war**/work

You need to set workDirectory explicitly to different value:

```
<plugin>
        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>2.1.1</version>
        <configuration>
                <workDirectory>target/overlay-war-folder</workDirectory>
                <overlays>
                        <overlay>
                                <groupId>your-group-id</groupId>
                                <artifactId>ui</artifactId>
                        </overlay>
                </overlays>
        </configuration>
</plugin>
```

Yet better solution would be to change module's name, as using keywords to name any project artifact is considered a bad practise, and you may expect further problems.